# Mod page speed image optimization filter not taking any effect

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I have site in word press and hosted on amazon server site speed is very fast.the ec2 ami instance  by default have mod pagespeed installed on server.

I have enable following filters to optimize image but its not taking any effect on webpagetest.org compress image section showing F grade with red colour.

my enabled filter list:-

```
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images,extend_cache
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_images
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_images
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_gif_to_png
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_jpeg_to_progressive
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_jpeg
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_png
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_webp
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters jpeg_subsampling
 ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg
```

Can anybody tell me why i am not able optimize images and how will i resolve this issue?